# JUnit test for an expected timeout

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I have a test of communication over a TCP socket where I expect the server to not respond within a set time frame when I send a certain message.

The servers behaviour is nothing I can control.

I know how to fail a test if it has not completed within a set time frame. But how can I do the opposite, make it pass for not completing within the timeframe?

I can use `@Test (timeout=1000)` to make a test fail if not complete within a second.

But, using Junit 4, is there a function to test for an expected timeout as a positive result? I.e. The test will fail if completed within the time frame and pass if not?

Comment: Does the timeout throw an exception? If it does, you can test for that timeout exception.

Comment: Be careful with this, I don't think you can `expect` the exception thrown by `timeout`. You could use a timer or just check the time of the operation then, if its over your desired time, throw an exception that you expect. Doesn't seem very efficient though.

Comment: Also, what exactly is the purpose of the test? If it's going out of your code's scope downstream to the server, I'm not sure how beneficial it is to test on your end. If you're expecting your code to handle the timeout, then you should just mock the socket and throw the exception back.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Good question. Actually you can do this using only `junit` tools. My idea is to inverse `Timeout` rule behaviour + use `expected` attribute of `Test` annotation. The only one limitation: you have to place your test in separate class, because `Rule` applies to all tests inside it:

```
public class Q37355035 {

    private static final int MIN_TIMEOUT = 100;

    @Rule
    public Timeout timeout = new Timeout(MIN_TIMEOUT) {
        public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {
            return new FailOnTimeout(base, MIN_TIMEOUT) {
                @Override
                public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                    try {
                        super.evaluate();
                        throw new TimeoutException();
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                }
            };
        }
    };

    @Test(expected = TimeoutException.class)
    public void givesTimeout() throws InterruptedException {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm building upon the great answer by Andremoniy, don't forget to upvote his answer if you like this one!

I used the following modification to skip a test if it doesn't finish in the expected time frame. The benefit of this is that the test will be marked as Skipped by JUnit instead of Successful. This is good for optimistic execution of tests which can sometimes hang or not finish fast enough, but you don't want to mark them as failed or delete them.

```
public class OptimisticTestClass {

    private static final int TEST_METHOD_TIMEOUT_MS = 100;

    @Rule
    public Timeout timeout = new Timeout(TEST_METHOD_TIMEOUT_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) {
        public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {
            return new FailOnTimeout(base, TEST_METHOD_TIMEOUT_MS) {
                @Override
                public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                    try {
                        super.evaluate();
                    } catch (TestTimedOutException e) {
                        Assume.assumeNoException("Test did not finish in the allocated time, skipping!", e);
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    };

    // The test times out and is skipped
    public void givesTimeout() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler in Java 9

```
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dormammu.bargain())
                     .orTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                     .handle((result, throwable) -> {
                         if (!(throwable instanceof TimeoutException)) {
                             Assertions.fail();
                         }
                         return result;
                     }).get();
```

If the method doesn't return within 1 second, it will time out. In handle method you can make sure TimeoutException was thrown, otherwise fail the test.